# LazyVerticalGrid of "columns/cells" not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

I was using LazyverticalGrid and I used **columns = GridCells.Fixed(6)** but it does not create equal or same size for all my items attached to my output.[image]

```
@Composable
fun WordSearch() {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        state = rememberLazyGridState(),
        modifier = Modifier,
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(6)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(listOfChars) { index, item ->
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .aspectRatio(1f)
                    .border(
                        1.dp,
                        Black
                    )
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = item, style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                    )
                )
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code so we can see what exactly you are doing? Also, is the image attached the output or the desired output?

Comment: @tomerpacific please I have updated.

Comment: Is the image what you currently have or what you want to have? If not, please add what you currently have/want to have.

Comment: @tomerpacific as you can see in the image I  highlight the portion of the issue. I was getting some minor space that was not set by me also the starting 2 columns were proper and the remaining had the space. and I was the same as the first two columns like all six.

Comment: Pardon me, but it's very hard to see the issue you are having in the image.

Comment: it's the same as the image minor "0.5" size issue.

Comment: @tomerpacific the minor space between 2 and 3 also 3 and 4 and 5 and 6.